# How to handles validate with two unique mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm beginner with mongoose and nodejs . I'm have two field unique in mongoose , how can I validate with it . Here is my code:

model

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    local:{
        email:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
        username:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
        password:{type:String,required:true}
    }
});
```

router

```
User.findOne({'local.email':req.body.email},function(err,user){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        if(user){
            res.json({message:'Email already exists'})
            next()
        }
    });

    User.findOne({'local.username':req.body.username},function(err,user){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    if(user){
        res.json({message:'Username already exists'})
        next()
    }
    })

    newUser = new User;
    newUser.local.email = req.body.email;
    newUser.local.username = req.body.username;
    newUser.local.password=req.body.password;
    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        res.json('Register Success');
    });
```

Im try this code above , but unfortunately it not work . When first time , I try post unique email , It work , but after it , I getting error `duplicate key error` . `Cant set header after they are send` . I'm not sure with code in my router . Can anyone show me what should I do ?

Comment: if(user){
        res.json({message:'Username already exists'})
        next()
    } remove next() from here , you are sending response twice to client

Comment: @Love-Kesh I remove it and still not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because once you cannot send response multiple times for a single request.

In your situation first time you create email & username and they are saved successfully but next time when you pass same email and username it goes to  this condition

```
if(user){
   res.json({message:'Email already exists'})
   next()
}
```

and return the response and then it checks for the username. There again it goes inside the condition

```
if(user){
   res.json({message:'Username already exists'})
   next()
}
```

and tries to return a response which throws you this error.

**Edit**

There are various ways of dealing with this sort of situations. I will explain one of them from as much as I have understood from your problem. Also, it is better to follow MVC practices properly. Let the queries be in the model.

Now you create a user with email, username, and password. While creating you also want to ensure that email and username are unique.

router.js

```
User.findDuplicate({'email':req.body.email, 'username' req.body.username},function(err,user){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    if(user){ // send duplicate message as entry exists
        if(user.local.email === req.body.email){
           res.json({message:'Email already exists'})
        }else if((user.local.username === req.body.username){
           res.json({message:'Username already exists'})
        }
    }else{ 
       // save the new user details
       // save query and return "Register Success"
    }
});
```

model.js

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
   local:{
       email:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
       username:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
       password:{type:String,required:true}
   }
});

userSchema.statics.findDuplicate = function(res, callback){
   this.findOne({$or:[{"local.email":res.email},{"local.username":res.username}]},callback);
}

// don't forget to register the model and export it and then require it in the router.js
```

Comment: thank you , now I know why I get error . But how can I fix that

Comment: You can query for email and username together and based on the result you either save it or send an error back.

Comment: what you mean is `User.find({'local.email' :req.body.email ,'local.username':req.body.username})`

Comment: does it solve your problem? if yes then use it. Also do you want the combination of username and email to be unique or both of them should be unique separately?

Comment: use this `find({$or:[{"local.email":req.body.email },{"local.username":req.body.username}]})` and based on its result you can either save or send error. Let me know if it works.

Comment: it's still not wokr . Can you try create a answer . I'm not sure about this code I tried

Comment: I don't know how you tried it because it worked for me.

Comment: Good luck. Happy programming :)

Answer (score 1):

**Do nested function (waterfall) code or use middleware function (for more detail [Middleware in node js](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/))**

```
router

User.findOne({'local.email':req.body.email},function(err,user){
  if(err) console.log(err)
    if(user){
      res.json({message:'Email already exists'})
      next()
    }else{


     User.findOne({'local.username':req.body.username},function(err,user){
      if(err) console.log(err)
        if(user){
          res.json({message:'Username already exists'})
          next()
        }else{


         newUser = new User;
         newUser.local.email = req.body.email;
         newUser.local.username = req.body.username;
         newUser.local.password=req.body.password;
         newUser.save(function(err){
          if(err) console.log(err)
            res.json('Register Success');
        });

       }
     })


   }
 });
```

Using middleware :

```
app.route('/create-user',checkUniqueuser, router.createUser);//example route given

function checkUniqueuser(req, res, next){

User.findOne({'local.email':req.body.email},function(err,user){
    if(err) console.log(err)
      if(user){
        res.json({message:'Email already exists'})
      }else{


       User.findOne({'local.username':req.body.username},function(err,user){
        if(err) console.log(err)
          if(user){
            res.json({message:'Username already exists'})

          }else{
            next();           

          }
        })


     }
   });

}
```

and in router.createUser :

```
  newUser = new User;
  newUser.local.email = req.body.email;
  newUser.local.username = req.body.username;
  newUser.local.password=req.body.password;
  newUser.save(function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err)
      res.json('Register Success');
  });
```

Comment: I'm not try it , but I think it probably work . But If I have more than 2 field , it will make my code unclean . Is there the way better ?

Comment: You can do using middleware function , pass field name and value dynamically

Comment: check my updated answer , u can beatify and reuse your function now @ThanhTùng